# C++11 non-blocking, long-running, producer consumer threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying to teach myself C++11 threading, and I would like to start a background producer thread at the beginning of the application, and have it run until application exit. I would also like to have consumer thread (which also runs for the life of the application).

A real-world example would be a producer thread listening on a Com port for incoming GPS data. Once a full message had been accumulated, it could be parsed to see if it was a message of interest, then converted into a string (say), and 'delivered back' to be consumed (update current location, for example).

My issue is I haven't been able to figure out how to do this without blocking the rest of the application when I 'join()' on the consumer thread.

Here is my very simplified example that hopefully shows my issues:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include "threadsafequeuetwo.h"

ThreadSafeQueueTwo<int> goods;
std::mutex mainMutex;

std::atomic<bool> isApplicationRunning = false;

void theProducer ()
{
    std::atomic<int> itr = 0;
    while(isApplicationRunning)
    {
        // Simulate this taking some time...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));

        // Push the "produced" value onto the queue...
        goods.push(++itr);

        // Diagnostic printout only...
        if ((itr % 10) == 0)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mainMutex);
            std::cout << "PUSH " << itr << " on thread ID: "
                  << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        }

        // Thread ending logic.
        if (itr > 100) isApplicationRunning = false;
    }
}

void theConsumer ()
{
    while(isApplicationRunning || !goods.empty())
    {
        int val;

        // Wait on new values, and 'pop' when available...
        goods.waitAndPop(val);

        // Here, we would 'do something' with the new values...
        // Simulate this taking some time...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

        // Diagnostic printout only...
        if ((val % 10) == 0)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mainMutex);
            std::cout << "POP " << val << " on thread ID: "
                  << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "MAIN running on thread ID: "
              << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    // This varaiable gets set to true at startup, and,
    // would only get set to false when the application
    // wants to exit.
    isApplicationRunning = true;

    std::thread producerThread (theProducer);
    std::thread consumerThread (theConsumer);

    producerThread.detach();
    consumerThread.join();      // BLOCKS!!! - how to get around this???

    std::cout << "MAIN ending on thread ID: "
              << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}
```

The ThreadSafeQueueTwo class is the thread safe queue implementation taken almost exactly as is from the "C++ Concurrency In Action" book. This seems to work just fine. Here it is if anybody is interested:

```
#ifndef THREADSAFEQUEUETWO_H
#define THREADSAFEQUEUETWO_H

#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template<typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueueTwo
{
public:
    ThreadSafeQueueTwo()
    {}

    ThreadSafeQueueTwo(ThreadSafeQueueTwo const& rhs)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        myQueue = rhs.myQueue;
    }

    void push(T newValue)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        myQueue.push(newValue);
        myCondVar.notify_one();
    }

    void waitAndPop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        myCondVar.wait(lock, [this]{return !myQueue.empty(); });
        value = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> waitAndPop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        myCondVar.wait(lock, [this]{return !myQueue.empty(); });
        std::shared_ptr<T> sharedPtrToT (std::make_shared<T>(myQueue.front()));
        myQueue.pop();
        return sharedPtrToT;
    }

    bool tryPop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        if (myQueue.empty())
            return false;
        value = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> tryPop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        if (myQueue.empty())
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        std::shared_ptr<T> sharedPtrToT (std::make_shared<T>(myQueue.front()));
        myQueue.pop();
        return sharedPtrToT;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        return myQueue.empty();
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex      myMutex;
    std::queue<T>           myQueue;
    std::condition_variable myCondVar;
};

#endif // THREADSAFEQUEUETWO_H
```

[Here's the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czEmK.png)

I know there are obvious issues with my example, but my main question is how would I run something like this in the background, without blocking the main thread?

Perhaps an even better way of trying to solve this is, is there a way that every time the producer has 'produced' some new data, could I simply call a method in the main thread, passing in the new data? This would be similar to queued signal/slots it Qt, which I am big fan of.

Comment: Well, what do you want "the rest of the application" do while producer and consumer run? Just do that in `main`, before you `join`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik - Aahhhhh, CLICK - now I get it (I think). So, if I wanted this to run for the duration of the application, I could just have some logic to detect that the application was closing down, and then call 'join()', there... Correct? My super simple tests with a small GUI seemed to show that that was the way it works!

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik - Forgot to say thanks! I apologize for the noob question. I was convinced you had to call join to get the thread going for some reason. Sigh.